# Check if value more than 5 times negative and mark them

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a really blockage this morning...

How can I check if a value repeats **consecutively** more than 5 times negatively and mark them? 
I mean it's easy to mark them if they are negative, but how to check if they occur more than 5 times?

UPDATE: Sorry I wasn't clear...

DATA:

```
+-------+-----------------+
| time  | V_preisereadDOT | 
+-------+-----------------+
| 00:00 |               5 |
| 01:00 |               1 |
| 02:00 |               2 |
| 03:00 |              -3 |
| 04:00 |              -8 |
| 05:00 |              -9 |
| 06:00 |               5 |
| 07:00 |               4 |
| 08:00 |              -9 |
| 09:00 |              -9 |
| 10:00 |              -5 |
| 11:00 |              -5 |
| 12:00 |              -4 |
| 13:00 |              -4 |
| 14:00 |               6 |
| 15:00 |               5 |
| 16:00 |               2 |
| 17:00 |               4 |
| 18:00 |              -4 |
| 19:00 |              -8 |
| 20:00 |              -9 |
| 21:00 |              -7 |
| 22:00 |               2 |
| 23:00 |               8 |
+-------+-----------------+
```

RESULT to get:

```
+-------+-----------------+----------+
| time  | V_preisereadDOT | 6negativ |
+-------+-----------------+----------+
| 00:00 |               5 |        0 |
| 01:00 |               1 |        0 |
| 02:00 |               2 |        0 |
| 03:00 |              -3 |        0 |
| 04:00 |              -8 |        0 |
| 05:00 |              -9 |        0 |
| 06:00 |               5 |        0 |
| 07:00 |               4 |        0 |
| 08:00 |              -9 |        1 |
| 09:00 |              -9 |        1 |
| 10:00 |              -5 |        1 |
| 11:00 |              -5 |        1 |
| 12:00 |              -4 |        1 |
| 13:00 |              -4 |        1 |
| 14:00 |               6 |        0 |
| 15:00 |               5 |        0 |
| 16:00 |               2 |        0 |
| 17:00 |               4 |        0 |
| 18:00 |              -4 |        0 |
| 19:00 |              -8 |        0 |
| 20:00 |              -9 |        0 |
| 21:00 |              -7 |        0 |
| 22:00 |               2 |        0 |
| 23:00 |               8 |        0 |
+-------+-----------------+----------+
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you mean 5 times consecutively, please, state it.

Comment: yes consecutively, the query is sorted by date/time

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
SELECT
  reading,
  COUNT(reading)
FROM data
WHERE negative = 1
GROUP BY reading
HAVING COUNT(reading) > 5
```